# Random message: Out-of-sync package detected in LANG1

Tags: raku

Working on  challenge 1 of [Perl Weekly Challenge 006](https://perlweeklychallenge.org/blog/perl-weekly-challenge-006/), I got this message running my code:

```
Out-of-sync package detected in LANG1 at env perl6
my $string= @*ARGS ?
  (value in braid: GLOBAL, value in $*PACKAGE: GLOBAL)
1-3,5-8,11,13
```

It has only shown itself *ONCE* through multiple invocations of identical code and identical input.

The exact invocation of the following code:
`./ch-1.p6 1,2,3 ,5,6,7,8,11,13`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
my $string= @*ARGS ?? @*ARGS.join(",")!! prompt "Enter numbers: ";
my $a=$string.split(",",:skip-empty)>>.trim.grep({!/^$/})>>.Int.Bag;
my @r1=$a.keys.sort;
my @diff=@r1.rotate >>-<< @r1;
my @p=(0,|map {|($^k,$k+1) if abs($^v) > 1}, @diff.kv);

@p.pop;
say join ",", map {@r1[$^a]==@r1[$^b]??@r1[$^a]!!"@r1[$^a]-@r1[$^b]"}, @p;
```

What does the message mean and why is randomly showing up?

**Update**

This has just happened again in a different program:

```
Out-of-sync package detected in LANG1 at env perl6                 
my $count =0;                                                      
my $nu
  (value in braid: GLOBAL, value in $*PACKAGE: GLOBAL)
```

Do I need to reinstall?

Comment: I'm trying to read more about this and apparently it has something to do with the regex when switching between Perl6, Quote, and Regex "languages", but I cannot pin down why it is not consistent..... Anyone else know more about how the braiding works in Perl6?